# Make all elements of <ul> element visibile

Tags: html, css

In the `<ul>`, its first descendent `<ul>` element is not shown if it has a descendent `<ul>` element itself.

i.e.

"Level II" elements are only visible if there are no "Level III" elements.

I'd like all elements in the child `<ul>` to show all of the `<li>` elements within it, as an unordered list would be rendered without any css.

```css
nav {
    background: black;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 120px;
    height: 100%;
}

nav ul {
    margin: 3rem 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

nav ul li {
    padding-top: 4rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
}


/** NAV LEVEL II **/

nav ul li > ul {
    position: fixed;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 120px;
    background: red;
    display: list;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 3rem 1rem;
}

nav ul li > ul li {
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
    background: green;
    display: inline;
}

/** NAV LEVEL III **/

nav ul li > ul li > ul li{

    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
    background: pink;
    display: block;

}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul> <!-- PARENT -->
        <li><a href="#">LEVEL I</a>
          <ul> <!-- FIRST CHILD - LEVEL II -->
            <li>Level II
              <ul> <!-- SECOND CHILD LEVEL III -->
                <li><a href="#">LEVEL III</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">LEVEL III</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">LEVEL III</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">LEVEL III</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Level II</li>
            <li>Level II</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">LEVEL I</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">LEVEL I</a></li>           
        <li><a href="#">LEVEL I</a> </li>
       <li><a href="#">LEVEL I</a></li>      
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: The wording is quite confusing. If I understand correctly, you want to show X list *only* if there are items in Y list. You can't do that with pure CSS, you'll need some javascript.

Comment: @TonyBarnes The question has been edited and it now appears to clearly want something totally different than that.

Comment: If you run the code snippet... Only level III elements are shown, I would like to show the level II elements aswell.

Comment: Level 3 elements are shown because you have them `position: fixed` and they're covering your level 2 elements.

Comment: Starter fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/fc0hnw13/ What sort of layout are you after?

Comment: Level II is showing, the problem is that `Level III` `ul` is in top of `Level II` and you can't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your `nav ul li > ul` selector. It is selecting any UL that is a direct descendant of a LI anywhere in a UL anywhere inside a nav. That applies to *both* UL children in your markup. So *both* UL children are fixed in the same position; your level III UL is covering your level II UL.

The best way to fix this is to start giving your elements so class names, which you can target in your CSS:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/97rsre2t/)

```css
nav {
    background: black;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 120px;
    height: 100%;
}
nav ul {
    margin: 3rem 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
nav ul li {
    padding-top: 4rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
}
/** NAV LEVEL II **/
.secondList {
    position: fixed;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 120px;
    background: red;
    display: list;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 3rem 1rem;
}
.secondList li {
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
    background: green;
    display: inline;
}
/** NAV LEVEL III **/
.thirdList li {
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
    background: pink;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul class="firstList"><!-- PARENT -->
        <li><a href="#">LEVEL I</a>
            <ul class="secondList"><!-- FIRST CHILD - LEVEL II -->
                <li>Level II
                    <ul class="thirdList"><!-- SECOND CHILD LEVEL III -->
                        <li><a href="#">LEVEL III</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">LEVEL III</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">LEVEL III</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">LEVEL III</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Level II</li>
                <li>Level II</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">LEVEL I</a> 
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">LEVEL I</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">LEVEL I</a> 
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">LEVEL I</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

This css would be applied to both the second & third level ul li structure.
So the position:fixed is applied to both 2nd & 3rd level. So both the levels are coming one above the other.

nav ul li > ul

So either add a class and target it appropriately. Eg: nav ul li > ul.second